# Finding Multiplier Matrix

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to find unknown matrix multiply matrix with knowing matrix

A*c=b

where b is defined vector, A is defined matrix 8x8, c is unknown vector.

I know, I can not divide matrix but what is the solution for this situation ??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a [system of simultaneous linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations). You can solve it using [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

As for matrix "division", what you really have in mind is an [inverse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_matrix), i.e. a matrix A<sup>-1</sup> such that

AA<sup>-1</sup>=A<sup>-1</sup>A=I

where I is the [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). If A is invertible then A*c=b is equivalent to c=A<sup>-1</sup>b.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Adam is certainly correct, but you should know that calculating the inverse of the matrix might not be the best solution.

Another to look into is LU decomposition and forward-back substitution.  It will be more computationally stable that full Gaussian elimination and calculating the inverse.

You solve the problem in steps like this:

1. Decompose A = LU; now you'll have LUc = b.  L is lower triangular; U is upper triangular.
2. Let y = Uc; solve Ly = b for y.
3. Now that you have y, solve for the c vector you want: y = Uc.